# Why is `numpy` rounding down `0.025` instead of rounding up

Tags: python, numpy

In `numpy`, some digits "finishing by `5`" are rounding up and down. For instance:

```
import numpy as np
np.array([0.025, 0.015]).round(2)
# array([0.02, 0.02])
```

Here `0.015` rounds up to `0.02` which is what I expect, but `0.025` rounds down to `0.02` instead of `0.03`, why so ?

Is it possible to fix that ? (Except using an epsilon for comparing float values)

Comment: See the doc on [`np.around`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html): _For values exactly halfway between rounded decimal values, NumPy rounds to the nearest even value. Thus 1.5 and 2.5 round to 2.0, -0.5 and 0.5 round to 0.0, etc. Results may also be surprising due to the inexact representation of decimal fractions in the IEEE floating point standard [1] and errors introduced when scaling by powers of ten._

Comment: Thank you @HansHirse. Should I delete my question ?